# How to find out the index/subscript of change for an array property using Swift Property Observers

Tags: arrays, swift, properties

I want to extend my usage of Swift Property Observers beyond scalar values like `Double`, `String`, `Int`, etc... to `[Double]`, `[String]`, `[Int]`. While it useful (using didSet & willSet) to know when the whole Array struct has been modified it is often beneficial to know which index in the array changed - for example so that unnecessary secondary computations can be avoided.

How is this achieved?

Comment: possible duplicate of [computed setter for a subscript of an array in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27675288/computed-setter-for-a-subscript-of-an-array-in-swift)

Comment: Thanks @jrturton. I was hoping for a more directly supported way (Swift syntax) but the suggested approach will work.

Comment: It would be nice to have it built in to Swift!