# Shorthand setter declaration for a subscript of an array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dynamic-properties

In my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27675288/computed-setter-for-a-subscript-of-an-array-in-swift), I asked how to write setter for a subscript of a computed property in Swift. I think my question was not substantial enough to be understood. The answer given was either incorrect or complicated for a small task. After a long thought, I still think maybe a brighter man can offer a more inspiring answer.

To subside confusion, my question is **if there is a shorthand setter declaration for a subscript of an array in Swift**. Because there is shorthand setter declaration for an array in swift, but not its subscript.

A **shorthand getter/setter declaration** is

```
var center: Point {
    get {
        let centerX = origin.x + (size.width / 2)
        let centerY = origin.y + (size.height / 2)
        return Point(x: centerX, y: centerY)
    }
    set {
        origin.x = newValue.x - (size.width / 2)
        origin.y = newValue.y - (size.height / 2)
    }
}
```

Basically, in a scenario where a set action for `action[i]` will cause `actionButton[i]` to be updated. There are basically two ways to do this quickly.

## First solution

```
func setActionAtIndex(index:Int, forValue newValue:SomeClass){
    action[index] = newValue
    self.updateActionButtonAtIndex(index)
}
```

This solution above is easy to understand, however, it requires a function, which takes two lines of code, in one class. **Not quite "Swift".**

## Second solution

```
var action: [SomeClass] {
    subscript(index:Int){
        set(index:Int,newValue:SomeClass){
           action[index] = newValue
           //extra action to be performed 
           updateActionButtonAtIndex(index)

        }
        get{
           return action[index]
        }
    }
}
```

Needless to say, this is absolutely **wrong** and this solution is **nonexistent**.

Why it is **wrong**?

```
Expected 'get', 'set', 'willSet', or 'didSet' keyword to start an accessor definition
```

### Hence, is there a solution that is **similar** to second solution but **works**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did think of another way, but I don't like it much. Use an extension to add another subscript to setter to Array - a setter that allows you to supply a callback. The problem with this approach is that you have remember to supply the callback! This puts the onus on whoever sets into the index, which is probably not what you had in mind. Still, it has the advantage, once configured, of brevity - and it takes `O(0)` time:

```
extension Array {
    subscript(ix:Int, f:(T,T,Int)->Void) -> T {
        set {
            let old = self[ix]
            self[ix] = newValue
            f(old,newValue,ix)
        }
        get {
            return self[ix]
        }
    }
}

class Thing {
    var arr : [Int] = [1, 2, 3]
    func f (oldv:Int, newv:Int, ix:Int) {
        println("changed \(oldv) to \(newv) at \(ix)")
    }
}

var t = Thing()
t.arr[1,t.f] = 100 // "changed 2 to 100 at 1"
```

Comment: This is kind of the approach I had, but I used a wrapper so you only set the callback once, and could set using subscripting as normal. Agree it's messier.

Comment: @jrturton Yes, I thought of the wrapper too, of course. But that seems like too much work. :) The real problem here is that (1) Array is a struct, not a class, so you can't subclass it, and (2) an extension can't declare a stored property (if it could, I would just store the last-changed index and have done).

Answer (score 4):

What you're not understanding is that an ordinary setter *is* the shorthand you are looking for. If an object has an array property and someone sets into that array, the setter is called.

For example:

```
class Thing {
    var arr : [Int] = [1, 2, 3] {
        didSet {
            println("I saw that")
        }
    }
}

var t = Thing()
t.arr[1] = 100 // "I saw that"
```

So all you have to do is use `didSet` to compare the new value to the old value and respond however you like to the change.

Comment: Oh yeah! Is that it? I was thinking about it in a much too complicated way. Last person gave me a whole new object class to handle it. I knew it could be done simpler. Thank you!

Comment: Nice answer! +1.  This is a consequence of swift's value semantics for arrays.

Comment: "Last person" here - is there a nice way to find out which value(s) have changed in this situation? I understood the original question to be about knowing the specific index.

Comment: If you want to know the exact index of change, you compare `oldValue` to `arr`(the name of your array) to find out of which index is the value changed, it normally just takes O(n) time

Comment: @jrturton See now my other answer - much faster, but less satisfactory, in my view.